# ¿Porque el contenido de mi plugin aparecen atras de mis entradas o paginas en WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo un problema, soy nuevo en esto, estoy desarrollando un Plugin para wordpress, pienso crear un botón que al momento de dar click te mande a una tabla de Amortización, primero no sabía cómo crear el botón, pero arreglándomelas cree un botón, el problema es que mi botón aparece atras de mis entradas o páginas de wordpress y cuando intento visualizarlas nada más se la pasa cargando y cargando y nunca entra a la visualización.
Agradecería infinitamente si me pudiesen ayudar o decirme que hacer, les dejo mi código de la Primera función, pienso que al dar click en el botón lo envié a mi segundo formulario con el método POST, y en el segundo formulario se hará la tabla en una hoja nueva.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: 
Plugin URI:
Description: 
Version: 2.0
Author: 
Author URI: 
Licence:
*/


echo "<form  action='Corrida.php' class='text-center' method='post'>";
echo "<div class='wp-block-button aligncenter is-style-outline'><a class='wp-block-button__link has-text-color has-background' style='background-color:'#a0a800';color:'#00a35f''><strong><em><code>GENERAR</code></em></strong></a></div>";

echo "<script>";
function Operacion($atts){
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
      'PrecioAuto' => '450000',
      'PlazoDeLaVenta' => '12',
      'PorcenajeFijoAuto' => '1.2'
    ), $atts);

    $U_PrecioCarro = $args["PrecioAuto"];
    $U_PrecioAuto = $args["PrecioAuto"];
    $U_PlazoDeLaVenta = $args["PlazoDeLaVenta"];
    $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = $args["PorcenajeFijoAuto"];

    //OPERACION
    $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto = ($U_PorcenajeFijoAuto/100)/12;
    $m=($U_PrecioAuto*$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto*(pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto), 
    ($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1))))/((pow((1+$U_PorcenajeFijoAuto),($U_PlazoDeLaVenta*1)))-1);

    return $U_PrecioCarro;
    return $U_PrecioAuto;
    return $U_PlazoDeLaVenta;
    return $U_PorcenajeFijoAuto;
    return $m;

  }
echo "</script>";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *atrás de mis entradas*?

Comment: Me late que es un problema del CSS